# Drawing on an image causes the photo to expand

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, image, draw

Hi I am build in an app that allow the users to use their finger to draw a line on top of an image, my issue is that when the user touches the screen to start drawing the images expands which make the image to be distorted.

Here is the code of the ViewController:

**UPDATE:  The code was updated to try to use a second image view also the suggestion from MailE**

```
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices

class NewAutographViewControler: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    
    var signEditMode: Bool = false
    
    @IBOutlet var btnEdit: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet var textFieldAlbum: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet var signImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func btnBackClick(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func btnEditClick(sender: AnyObject) {
        if signEditMode {
            signEditMode = false
            signImageView.backgroundColor = nil
            btnEdit.title = "Edit"
            signImageView.gestureRecognizers?.removeAll()
        }
        else {
            signEditMode = true
            btnEdit.title = "Done"
            signImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.5)
            let tap = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTap:"))
            tap.delegate = self
            signImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
            signImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        }
    }
    
    func handleTap(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
        let recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer = sender!
        
        let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)
        if let view = recognizer.view {
            view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
                y:view.center.y + translation.y)
        }
        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
        
    }
    
    func getSaveResponse( response: Bool){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        print("getSaveResponse")
        print(response)
        if response {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Save", message:  "Autograph Saved!", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            
            let save = UIAlertAction(title: "New", style: .Default) { (alertAction: UIAlertAction!) ->
                Void in
                self.newPhoto()
            }
            
            let done = UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .Default) { (alertAction: UIAlertAction!) ->
                Void in
                self.btnBackClick(self)
            }
            
            alert.addAction(save)
            alert.addAction(done)
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
        }
        else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Save", message:  "Uh Oh! Autograph could not be save!", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        }

    }
    
    @IBAction func btnSaveClick(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("save click")
        mergeImages()
        let newPhotoAlbum = PhotoAlbum()
        let validate = newPhotoAlbum.saveImage(imageView.image!, funParam: getSaveResponse)
        if validate == false {
            getSaveResponse(false)
        }
        
    }
    
    //drawing variables
    var lastPoint = CGPoint.zero
    var red: CGFloat = 0.0
    var green: CGFloat = 0.0
    var blue: CGFloat = 0.0
    var brushWidth: CGFloat = 10.0
    var opacity: CGFloat = 1.0
    var swiped = false
    var imageSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 0,height: 0)
    
    //end-drawing variables
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        newPhoto()
        
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    
    func newPhoto() {
        if (UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)){
            let picker = UIImagePickerController()
            picker.delegate = self
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
            //picker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
            //picker.allowsEditing = true
            self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Camera Error", message: "No Camera Detected!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            //alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
            
            let dismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (alertAction: UIAlertAction!) ->
                Void in
                self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
            }
            alertController.addAction(dismiss)
            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
            
        }
        
        
        
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]){
        print("Received image from camera")
        //let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! String
        var originalImage:UIImage? //, editedImage:UIImage?, imageToSave:UIImage?
        //let compResult:CFComparisonResult = CFStringCompare(mediaType as NSString!, kUTTypeImage, CFStringCompareFlags.CompareCaseInsensitive)
        //if ( compResult == CFComparisonResult.CompareEqualTo ) {
            
            //editedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as! UIImage?
            originalImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage?
            
            /*if ( editedImage != nil ) {
                imageToSave = editedImage
            } else {
                imageToSave = originalImage
            }
            imageView.image = imageToSave
            imageView.reloadInputViews()
        }*/
        imageView.image = originalImage
        picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        imageSize = (originalImage?.size)!
        //print(imageView.frame.size)
    }
    
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

    //drawing-functions
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if signEditMode {
            return
        }
            swiped = false
            if let touch:UITouch = touches.first! as UITouch {
                //lastPoint = touch.locationInView(self.view)
                lastPoint = touch.locationInView(signImageView)
            }
        
    }
    
    func drawLineFrom(fromPoint: CGPoint, toPoint: CGPoint) {
        
        /*var scale: CGFloat = 1.0;
        if UIScreen.mainScreen().respondsToSelector(Selector("scale")) {
            let tmp: CGFloat = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
            if (tmp > 1.5) {
                scale = 2.0;
            }
        }
        
        if(scale > 1.5) {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, false, scale);
        } else {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size);
        }
        print(imageView.frame.size)
        */
        
        // 1
        //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
        //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.imageView.frame.size)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.signImageView.bounds.size, false, 0)
        
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        //tempImageView.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height))
        //imageView.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height))
        signImageView.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.signImageView.bounds.size.width, height: self.signImageView.bounds.size.height))
        
        // 2
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, fromPoint.x, fromPoint.y)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, toPoint.x, toPoint.y)
        
        // 3
        CGContextSetLineCap(context, .Round)
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, brushWidth)
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, red, green, blue, 1.0)
        CGContextSetBlendMode(context, .Normal)
        
        // 4
        CGContextStrokePath(context)
        
        // 5
        //tempImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        //tempImageView.alpha = opacity
        //imageView.autoresizingMask =  [.FlexibleRightMargin, .FlexibleLeftMargin, .FlexibleBottomMargin, .FlexibleTopMargin]
        //Change from Fit to Fill
        //imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
        
        signImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        // 6
        swiped = true
        if let touch:UITouch = touches.first! as UITouch {
            //let currentPoint = touch.locationInView(view)
            let currentPoint = touch.locationInView(signImageView)
            drawLineFrom(lastPoint, toPoint: currentPoint)
            
            // 7
            lastPoint = currentPoint
        }

    }
    
    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if signEditMode {
            return
        }
        if !swiped {
            // draw a single point
            drawLineFrom(lastPoint, toPoint: lastPoint)
        }
        
        // Merge tempImageView into mainImageView
        /*UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.frame.size)
        imageView.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height), blendMode: .Normal, alpha: 1.0)
        imageView.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height), blendMode: .Normal, alpha: opacity)
        imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        
        tempImageView.image = nil*/
    }
    //end-drawing-functions
    
    //To Merge Sign and Image
    func mergeImages(){
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size, false, 0)
        imageView.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageView.bounds.size.width, height: imageView.bounds.size.height), blendMode: .Normal, alpha: 1.0)
        signImageView.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageView.bounds.size.width, height: imageView.bounds.size.height), blendMode: .Normal, alpha: opacity)
        //added contentMode
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
        imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        
        signImageView.image = nil
    }
}
```

May I ask what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem may occur when your device supported retina or UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeScale > 1
Try
 `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.imageView.bounds.size, false, 0.0)` 
instead of 
`UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.imageView.frame.size)`

Comment: Hi I tried that and the problem, I have updated the code with my latest changes, the differences are :
1. I am using to different images view.
2. I am using your suggestion.

Comment: Your UIImageView and Image is same ratio (width/height of it same value)  signImageView.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.signImageView.bounds.size.width, height: self.signImageView.bounds.size.height))
        will draw your image to Fill UIImageView Rect

Comment: So why is this expand thing happening then, am I missing something else?